# How to change CKAN default css

Tags: ckan

I am using CKAN runnin on docker 2.8.1 version, and i want to change some default css of ckan without creating new theme/plugin etc.. as documentation sugest because i am having issues with it.

If it is possible to change css of CKAN without creating my own what files i should change, since i change for example main.css nothing happens i try to change .less files also nothing happens. In my case i wanted to change color but no matter what i changed color would stay same.

It is clear to me that i am doing something wrong bug hard to pin point what, i even try using paster css, paster less(i get error here).

If some alredy changed this aspects could u please point me out in right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you want to change the look and feel of CKAN web interface. If it's a simple change of logo, about or intro text, some custom css and style you can use ckan admin option. For more info check the [customizing look and feel](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/sysadmin-guide.html#customizing-look-and-feel)

If you need more advanced changes for e.g new templates, overriding existing once etc follow the [theming guide](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/theming/index.html)

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, just clarify without creating new templates/themes it is not possible to change default ones provided by CKAN?

Comment: Yes, check the first link I've sent.

Comment: Thanks, first link solved my issue. I made stupid mistake of not creating systemadmin so i was not able to use this features. Once again thanks.

Comment: Great to hear that. Pozdrav :)